# Jhipster hibernate sequence not generating new ids

Tags: postgresql, java-8, jhipster

Jhipster hibernate sequence is not returning ids from the sequence pool

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value 
violates unique constraint "pk_video_catalog" Detail: Key (id)=(2) already 
exists. at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutor
Impl.java:2440) at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) 
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatemen
t.java:143) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPre
```

Entity that has the sequence generator

```java
public class VideoCatalog extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;
```

the database has `hibernate_sequence` as the sequence

Comment: It looks like you are using the default sequence. Does that match your expectations?

Comment: Any chance that there's an external system also using this sequence?

Comment: For some reason whatever I did it doesn't work. recreating the entity etc.. I deleted the entity and recreated it which worked.